# Bash: How to set changing variable in PS1, updating every prompt

Tags: bash, unix, console, ps1

I've searched for quite a while, but haven't been able to find a post or any information whatsoever about adding a variable that is, well, variable (i.e. changing) within PS1 in bash, that will update every time a new prompt occurs. In concreto, I would like the width of the prompt to span across the whole terminal window, e.g.:

```
7zS2::awesome| --------------------------------------------------------- ~/.config/awesome
```

This is what I have so far, omitting color codes for legibility:

```
mytest=$PWD
mynext="$(basename $PWD)"
mylength=$((${#mytest}+${#mynext}))
length=$(($mylength+6))
PS1='7zS2::\W| $(printf "\\u2500%.0s" $(seq $length $(tput cols))) \w\n\$'
```

Which works perfectly whenever I

```
exec bash
```

to reset the prompt.

However, I would like it to work without me having to reload bash. Surely there must be a way of doing this, as \w, \W and of the likes are unique and updated every prompt as well. Any way of easily doing this?
Thanks!

7zS2

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Place your code into a file, I'm calling it `gash.sh` in my home directory, with a small modification: replace the PS1 assignment with `echo`, and replace the single quotes with double.

```
mytest=$PWD
mynext="$(basename $PWD)"
mylength=$((${#mytest}+${#mynext}))
length=$(($mylength+6))
echo "7zS2::\W| $(printf \\u2500%.0s $(seq $length $(tput cols))) \w\n\$"
```

then in your startup file set PS1:

```
PS1='$(~/gash.sh)'
```

Comment: Nice and quick fix, thanks! Only problem now is that it's printing it out weirdly, but the length is perfect every time. This is what it currently looks like:
 
    ?------------------------------------\ \w\n$33[m\]| -----------------------------

Comment: I.e. it won't read in the escape codes nor color options. Any suggestions on this one? Thank you