# Bash: How to set changing variable in PS1 and preserve PS1 codes like \w

Tags: bash, unix, console, ps1

I'd like the include a dynamic variable in my PS1 prompt, let's say the 5th folder in the path.  I'd also like to include some other PS1 codes (maybe color, username or current directory).

I have a script to get the 5th folder and echo it with one of the escape PS1 codes.

```
demo_prompt.sh

folder5=$(cut -d / -f 6 <<< $PWD)<br>
echo "$folder5 \W $ "
```

This .bashrc sets PS1 to the output of the script.

```
.bashrc

PS1='$(~/demo_prompt.sh)'
```

If I keep the PS1 definition in .bashrc in single quotes:

Pro:  The 5th folder dynamically updates while I change directories as desired,

Con:  \W appears in the prompt rather than resolving to the current folder name.

If I change the PS1 definition in .bashrc from single quotes to double quotes:

Pro:  \W resolves properly to be the current directory

Con:  The 5th folder is fixed to the value when I source .bashrc

How can I achieve both the \W resolving and the 5th folder dynamically updating?

I've more or less followed the idea here and am essentially asking the followup question that went unanswered. [Bash: How to set changing variable in PS1, updating every prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331293/bash-how-to-set-changing-variable-in-ps1-updating-every-prompt))

Quote:  "I.e. it won't read in the escape codes nor color options. Any suggestions on this one?"

Thanks!

Comment: Escape sequences like `\W` should be expanded no matter how you set `PS1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

demo_prompt.sh

```
folder5='$(cut -d / -f 6 <<< $PWD)\n'
echo "$folder5 \W $ "
```

and .bashrc

```
PS1="$(~/demo_prompt.sh)"
```

Comment: Ah ha, I had to single quote the line in demo_prompt.sh.  Thanks!  I guess without the quote it was immediately resolving the variable and now it's passing the string itself upstream to be resolved later.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='dir5=$(cut -d / -f 3 <<< "$PWD")'
PS1='$dir5 \W $ '
```

(Note the quotes)

`PROMPT_COMMAND` runs before the prompt is displayed and allows you to set global variables. You can also set it to a function call that would set global variables, call scripts, or call your script directly from `PROMPT_COMMAND`.